# Positive moments of independent variables are also independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

Suppose we have $X$ and $Y$ which are random variables and they are also independent and we also have $i, j \in \mathbb{N}_{+}$. Is it true that $X^{i}$ and $Y^{j}$ are independent? Actually I need the proof for a special case where $i = 1$ and $j = 2$ and both $X$ and $Y$ are normal variables but I would prefer a simple proof for the general version.

Comment: Hint: Given a set $E\subset\Bbb R$ there exists $F\subset \Bbb R$ so that $X^i\in E$ if and only if $X\in F$.

Comment: More generally, $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent for any two measurable mappings $f,g$.

Comment: Ah I get it. Suppose we have $X^i \in F$ then there is a $F'$ such that $X^i \in F \Leftrightarrow X \in F$. The same is true for $Y^j$ and we can use the independent of the original variables on the $pdf$. Seems like a more generic relation is true for $f, g$ function which are in this case $f(x) = x^i$ and $g(x) = x^j$

Comment: @saz: Ah yeah I saw your comment after I made mine.

Comment: Should I delete this question?